# Can i move existing GA code to new site on SAME domain?

Tags: analytics

So, i have one website with GA code on it, we are upgrading to V2, domain, links, etc stays all the same, can i just copy GA js from old sites source code and paste it to new website?
Will it keep all goals/adwords intact?

Comment: Are you upgrading to website-v2 or Google Analytics V2 (Universal Tracking)?

Comment: Website, i already have universal tracking installed.

Answer (score 0):

If your Universal Analytics integration is limited to having the code snippet before the closing `</body>` tag of your old website, then copying the snippet to the new website will indeed be sufficient.

Beware, though, of any custom tracking that calls the GA functions from Javascript, for example on Ajax navigations. You will have to migrate those as well.